# datePicker in jQuery UI not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to call the beforeShowDay function in jquery UI datepicker, but I found that the location 
of beforeShowDay matters and I have no clue.

Code would help:

```
<script>
    var datePickerOptions = {
        minDate: 'today',
        beforeShowDay: available
    };

    /*This is a function only let datePicker show the dates in dateList*/
    var available = function(date){
        window.console.log("in");
        var dmy = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        if($.inArray( dmy, dateList ) !== -1 ) {
            return [true, "", "Available"];
        }
        else {
            return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
        }
    };

    var init = function(availableDates) {
        $('.datePicker').datepicker(datePickerOptions);
    };
</script>
```

If I write it in this way, the minDate would work, but the beforeShowDay wouldn't, the console didn't print 'in'.

But if I write it in this way:

```
var init = function(availableDates) {
    $('.datePicker').datepicker({
        minDate: 'today',
        beforeShowDay: available
    });
};
```

it would work.I don't see the real difference between these two methods, and I really want to use the first method.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is because when `available` is used to create the `datePickerOptions` object it is not initialized with a value, so it has a value of undefined which is same as not passing the option in this case. You can move the creation of `datePickerOptions` after the `available` variable is initialized to fix the problem.

```
/*This is a function only let datePicker show the dates in dateList*/
var available = function(date){
    window.console.log("in");
    var dmy = (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate() + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if($.inArray( dmy, dateList ) !== -1 ) {
        return [true, "", "Available"];
    }
    else {
        return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
    }
};

var datePickerOptions = {
    minDate: 'today',
    beforeShowDay: available
};

var init = function(availableDates) {
    $('.datePicker').datepicker(datePickerOptions);
};
```